# System.InvalidOperationException: 'When executing a command, parameters must be exclusively database parameters or values.'

Tags: sql, entity-framework

I have following stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AMRSetStatus]
    (@JobId AS uniqueidentifier,
     @Status AS nvarchar(32),
     @ObjectsProcessed int = NULL,
     @TotalExpectedSPObjects int = NULL,
     @TotalDurationInMs int = NULL)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    UPDATE jobscans WITH (rowlock) 
    SET Updated = GETDATE(), 
        StatusToXML = CASE WHEN StatusToXML <> 'JobEnd' THEN @Status ELSE StatusToXML END,
        ObjectsProcessed = CASE 
                              WHEN StatusToXML = 'JobEnd' THEN ObjectsProcessed 
                              WHEN @ObjectsProcessed = 0 THEN ObjectsProcessed 
                              WHEN @ObjectsProcessed IS NULL THEN ObjectsProcessed 
                              ELSE @ObjectsProcessed 
                           END,
        TotalExpectedSPObjects = CASE 
                                    WHEN StatusToXML = 'JobEnd' THEN TotalExpectedSPObjects  
                                    WHEN @TotalExpectedSPObjects = 0 THEN TotalExpectedSPObjects 
                                    WHEN @TotalExpectedSPObjects IS NULL THEN TotalExpectedSPObjects 
                                    ELSE @TotalExpectedSPObjects 
                                 END,
        TotalDurationInMs = CASE 
                               WHEN StatusToXML = 'JobEnd' THEN TotalDurationInMs  
                               WHEN @TotalDurationInMs = 0 THEN TotalDurationInMs 
                               WHEN @TotalDurationInMs IS NULL THEN TotalDurationInMs 
                               ELSE @TotalDurationInMs 
                            END
    WHERE JobId = @JobId
END
GO
```

This is my C# code:

```
public void AMRSetStatus(Guid jobId, string status, int? objectsProcessed, int? totalExpectedSPObjects, int? totalDurationInMs)
{
    var jobIdParam = new SqlParameter("@JobId", jobId);
    var statusParam = new SqlParameter("@Status", status);

    var objectsProcessedParam = new SqlParameter("@ObjectsProcessed", objectsProcessed);
    var totalExpectedSPObjectsParam = new SqlParameter("@TotalExpectedSPObjects", totalExpectedSPObjects);
    var totalDurationInMsParam = new SqlParameter("@TotalDurationInMs", totalDurationInMs);

    this.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("exec AMRSetStatus @JobId,@Status,@ObjectsProcessed,@TotalExpectedSPObjects,@TotalDurationInMs", jobIdParam, statusParam, objectsProcessed, totalExpectedSPObjects, totalDurationInMs);
}
```

But I get following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'When executing a command,
> parameters must be exclusively database parameters or values.'

If I only add first two parameters it works. Cant you send nullable int's or any pointers?

Comment: Are you f.... kidding me. Been looking for hours for comma errors so starred me blind. Thanks, appreciated. Please post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing SQL parameters and values. Instead of passing `objectsProcessed` to `Database.ExecuteSqlCommand()`, provide the parameter `objectsProcessedParam` and so on.